# DPC WatchDog Violation after Selenium is ran with python

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, python, selenium, dpc

I have recently decided to move my web automation scripts from Google Colab where they worked fine,  to my own PC. After getting the correct webdriver(for chrome, version 89), I tried launching a python script and after a few minutes, the PC crashed and gave a DPC WATCHDOG VIOLATION stop code. If I don't launch my script, it works all fine. I have googled the question but couldn't find a good solution or reason why this happens. My script is below:

```python
from selenium import webdriver
wd = webdriver.Chrome()
wd.get("https://www.labirint.ru")
search_bar = wd.find_element_by_id("search-field")
search_bar.send_keys("978-5-907180-08-6")
search_bar.submit()
results = wd.find_elements_by_class_name("card-column_gutter")
print(results[0].text)
```

I have downloaded my chromedriver.exe from here: https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

Comment: [`DPC WATCHDOG VIOLATION`](https://superuser.com/questions/1132398/what-is-dpc-watchdog?rq=1) is a catch all exception caused by multiple things.  It basically means that a process, caused an interrupt request level (IRQL) to happen for a prolonged period of time (longer than 100 ms), it basically was caused by the driver you are attempting to use.

Comment: so the chromedriver.exe file?

Comment: It's either the driver or the script, to determine which one, I would debug the script to determine which instruction causes the error.

Comment: The script gives no apparent errors. The pc just crashes @Ramhound

Comment: At which instruction exactly?

Comment: I think on the `search_bar = ...` because I ran it up to that point, closed the chrome window that it opened and then ran it again up to `search_bar.sendkeys()` at which point it crashed without showing me any output, even though It usually prints a listening log first thing. @Ramhound

Comment: @Ramhound It's the driver. I have no idea why but the geckodriver + firefox combo works perfectly. and without errors. and crashes